# When using a subordinating conjuction between two independent statements, do I use a comma?

Tags: commas, subordinate-clauses

When using a subordinating conjuction between two independent statements, do I use a comma? For example:

> Arriving near the noble’s personal quarters, Haru saw an irritable Fujita leave the noble’s room(,) as she threw her arms up in defeat and muttered under her breath.

*As* is the subordinating conjunction, and both clauses could stand alone. So would I use the comma?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Can you please clarify what you would like to express in your example sentence (see also Edwin Ashworth’s answer) and to whom *she* and *her* refer in the subordinate clause, Fujita or Haru?

Comment: In that sentence, the comma is not needed seeing as the two thoughts are connected.

Comment: I think it would actually read much better if you recast the sentence to:  "...Haru saw an irritable Fujita leave the noble's room, throwing her arms up in defeat and muttering under her breath."

Answer (score 1):

Note the difference between

*I will try to get some sleep as we are going to London tomorrow.*

and

*I will try to get some sleep, as we are going to London tomorrow.*

Both are correct, but the first sentence strongly suggests the 'while' sense of 'as', whereas the second virtually demands the 'because' sense. A dash or an ellipsis would muddy the waters.

The example given by OP is perhaps over-complex but the 'because' sense is probably not available. A comma could be included for ease of reading here.